# OpenID Redirect URI adds a # symbol

Tags: asp.net, redirect, openid-connect

I have configured an OpenID Connection application on OneLogin (not sure the provider matters) with a configured post MFA authentication redirect uri of

http://localhost:4200/LoginResponse.aspx?

The code behind my LoginResponse.aspx page grabs the returned id_token and processes it.

The issue is that after my initial redirect to the MFA login and successful login/MFA validation, the redirect is coming to

http://localhost:4200/LoginResponse.aspx#id_token=12345678987...........

Note the "#" symbol after my .aspx extension. This is corrupting the parameter string that is returned and not allowing me to grab the value of id_token from the Response.

After the redirect comes back, if I simply manually replace the "#" with a "?" and hit enter, my LoginResponse.aspx page loads fine and finds the id_token and processes it with my business logic.

My question is, how can I get the redirect to actually return to "LoginResponse.aspx?" so that I can grab the parameters.

On my OpenID Application I have tried the following options as Redirect URIs

- LoginResponse
- LoginResponse.aspx
- LoginResponse.aspx?
- LoginResponse.aspx?action=test

Did that last one to see if I could get around the ? not being there. But that just redirected the page to "LoginResponse.aspx?action=test#id_token=..............." So again, I could not grab the "id_token" variable out of the URL Response/QueryString.

I just cannot figure out how to get rid of this unwanted "#" sign and have a "?" after my .aspx extension.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the implicit flow to retrieve the tokens and in this flow you can either get back the tokens in the URL with the #. The # is added to make sure the tokens are not sent back to the server, instead they just stay in the browser. If it was a #, then the secret tokens would be sent back to the server and end up in various logs and creating various security issues.

I don't know how you implemented the client, but in OpenID Connect, if you add this parameter "&response_mode=form_post" to the initial authorization request, then you will get back the token using a POST request instead. just like this picture shows:

[image]

PS, I doubt you can get back the tokens using a ? instead of #.

Comment: Adding response_mode and then getting my response values from "HttpContext.Current.Request.Form" worked. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Great! feel free to mark the answer as acceped if you like!